# Extend a block and use new function in template

Tags: magento-1.9

I've created a module to check which country the user has selected.

If the country is not in the EU, Magento should return a additional info when entering step 5 from the one page checkout.

This is my code:

`app/code/local/Vendor/CustomsDuty/Block/Onepage.php`:

```
<?php

class Vendor_CustomsDuty_Block_Frontend_CustomsDuty extends Mage_Checkout_Block_Onepage_Review_Info {

    public $_customsDuty;

    protected function _construct(){
        parent::_construct();
    }


    public function setCustomsDuty($input){
        $this->_customsDuty = $input;
    }

    public function getCustomsDuty(){

        //$this->setCustomsDuty($this->getShipping);
        $this->setCustomsDuty("123123123");

        return $this->_customsDuty;

    }

}
```

My `app/code/local/Vendor/CustomsDuty/etc/config.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
<config>
        <modules>
            <Vendor_CustomsDuty>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
            </Vendor_CustomsDuty>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <customsduty>
                    <class>Vendor_CustomsDuty_Block</class>
                </customsduty>
            </blocks>
        </global>
        <frontend>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <configurable module="Vendor_CustomsDuty">
                        <file>configurable.xml</file>
                    </configurable>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
     </config>
```

And I enabled the module in `app/etc/modules/` by creating a custom xml.

In the `/app/design/frontend/vendor/default/template/checkout/onepage/review/info.phtml` I've put in the following:

```
<?php

    $this->getCustomsDuty(); 

?>
```

However, at the desired position, there is no output, not even a echo or a failure. What have I done wrong here? What do I need to get at least ANYTHING on the desired position?

Comment: provide code of your `configurable.xml` file

Comment: There is no need to actually have a configurable.xml, so there is none. I've just deleted it from my XML again as it rendered useless.

Comment: you need some layout file to tell you magento that for this phtml file this block is there